# Service Stopes when I end application

Tags: android

when I end application with End Button at task manager , my service stops with this ,
my service process uses the same activity process and I do not want to use service in other process . 
is there any way when user stop activity , it do not closes service with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new app with your service. Start this service from an activity which is another app. So the activity and service are in two different apps, so if you stop activity app which won't affect service app.

Comment: I started Service at BOOT_COMPLETED , so I do called it in my application .

Comment: if you are not using service in different process, it will be stopped automatically when you ends app process. so you have to use two different processes and use intent receivers for inter process communication.